# Google Play Store keeps crashing on Android Virtual Device

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, simulator

I am running my Android app through Android Studio on the Android Virtual Device. I have tried using multiple different virtual devices, however the Google Play app continually crashes whenever I try to open it. I have also tried updating the Google play app through Android Studio, but the Google Play app continues to crash. Any ideas on what I may be missing? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of crash do you get? Is there some text?

Maybe this can help. https://www.howtogeek.com/248924/how-to-fix-the-android-play-store-when-it-constantly-force-closes/